# Add a row to each dataframe in a list with the column median using map_dfr

Tags: r, list, dataframe, purrr, tibble

I have this example list that contains 3 dataframes:

```
library(tidyverse)
list_df <- iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    slice(1:3) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    group_split(Species)
```

**I want to** add a new **row** at the end of each dataframe that shows the **column median**

**My try so far** (and earlier this day I am sure it worked) is not working:

```
list_df %>%
    map_dfr([,1:4], ~ .x %>%
                add_row(!!!map(., median)))
```

**I want to learn** why my code is not working and what exactly `!!!` is for ins this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[, 1:4]` doesn't include the data i.e. it only shows the index and thus it fails

```
list_df %>% 
        map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
             add_row(!!! map(.[1:4], median)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa    
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa    
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa    
 4          4.9         3.2          1.4         0.2 <NA>      
 5          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
 6          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
 7          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
 8          6.9         3.2          4.7         1.5 <NA>      
 9          6.3         3.3          6           2.5 virginica 
10          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica 
11          7.1         3            5.9         2.1 virginica 
12          6.3         3            5.9         2.1 <NA>
```

---

If we want to add a row with the group information, another option is `group_modify` (without splitting)

```
iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    slice(1:3) %>%
    group_modify(~ .x %>% 
                add_row(!!! map(.x, median))) %>% 
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
   <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 setosa              5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
 2 setosa              4.9         3            1.4         0.2
 3 setosa              4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
 4 setosa              4.9         3.2          1.4         0.2
 5 versicolor          7           3.2          4.7         1.4
 6 versicolor          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5
 7 versicolor          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5
 8 versicolor          6.9         3.2          4.7         1.5
 9 virginica           6.3         3.3          6           2.5
10 virginica           5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9
11 virginica           7.1         3            5.9         2.1
12 virginica           6.3         3            5.9         2.1
```

---

If we want to add the `median` rows,

```
iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    slice(1:3) %>%
    group_modify(~ .x %>% 
                add_row(!!! map(.x, median))) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    summarise(across(2:5, ~ c(.[rn < max(rn)], 
      sum(.[rn == max(rn)]))), Species = c(Species[rn != max(rn)],
        "Total"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>  
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 1      
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 1      
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 1      
 4          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 2      
 5          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 2      
 6          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 2      
 7          6.3         3.3          6           2.5 3      
 8          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 3      
 9          7.1         3            5.9         2.1 3      
10         18.1         9.4         12           3.8 Total
```

Comment: Ok master. Incredibly as always. Thank you very much. Now if I want to sum these last rows (e.g. the medians) to one final row in one dataframe. Could you please assist me. And what `!!!` does here exactly.

Comment: @TarJae  According to `?"!!!` - `The big-bang operator !!! forces-splice a list of objects. The elements of the list are spliced in place, meaning that they each become one single argument.`

Comment: @TarJae when you say to sum last rows, do you only want to return the `median`  row and then sum only those?  Then, you may not need `add_row`

Comment: Yes exactly. add_row is just by interest to see what is going on.

Comment: @TarJae please check if the update helps you